# To Check duplicate row using conditional format

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, conditional-formatting

I want to check the data across several columns to see if there are duplicate rows.
To do this, I had to make a new column using

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(A2:A&C2:C)
```

Then I check if there are duplicates in this column with custom formula for conditional formatting

```
=AND(COUNTIF($D$2:$D,$D2)>1,NOT(ISBLANK($A2)))
```

This works, but it is dirty because I had to add a new column to the sheet, which is not allowed in some situation. Is there any other approach to do this using formula only?

Live sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1tKcUIP93opONONrVc5efnB2B4LcKsD5a8_v38Zi3pQY/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

Try only `COUNTIFS()` in custom CF rule.

```
=COUNTIFS($A$2:$A,$A2,$C$2:$C,$C2)>1
```

[image]